Clangd In included file: 'llvm/ADT/DenseMapInfo.h' file not found
I want to use llvm to write some programs, but when I include the llvm files I meet this problems:

My settings.json is :
  "clangd.path": "/usr/bin/clangd",
  "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++20",
  "clangd.fallbackFlags": [
    "-std=c++20"
  ],


Did you enable compile_commands.json generation in your build system?

I have generate compile_commands.json, but cannot deal with the problem @HolyBlackCat
